# Recursive division algorithm for two n bit numbers

Tags: algorithm, recursion

In the below division algorithm, I am not able to understand why multiplying q and r by two works and also why r is incremented if x is odd.

Please give a theoretical justification of this recursive division algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

```
function divide(x, y) 
   if x = 0: 
      return (q, r) = (0, 0) 
   (q, r) = divide(floor(x/2), y) 
   q = 2q, r = 2r 
   if x is odd: 
      r = r + 1 
   if r ≥ y: 
      r = r − y, q = q + 1
   return (q, r)
```

Comment: If you don't understand an algorithm, you should try to get it to work with paper and pencil. Hint: you're working on  a number in binary representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's assume you want to divide `x` by `y`, i.e. represent `x = Q * y + R`

Let's assume that `x` is even. You recursively divide `x / 2` by `y` and get your desired representation for a smaller case: `x / 2 = q * y + r`.

By multiplying it by two, you would get: `x = 2q * y + 2r`. Looking at the representation you wanted to get for `x` in the first place, you see that you have found it! Let `Q = 2q` and `R = 2r` and you found the desired `Q` and `R`.

If `x` is odd, you again first get the desired representation for a smaller case: `(x - 1) / 2 = q * y + r`, multiply it by two: `x - 1 = 2q * y + 2r`, and send `1` to the right: `x = 2q * y + 2r + 1`. Again, you have found `Q` and `R` you wanted: `Q = 2q`, `R = 2r + 1`.

The final part of the algorithm is just normalization so that `r < y`. `r` can become bigger than `y` when you perform multiplication by two.

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm PuzzleSolve(k,S,U) :
Input: An integer k, sequence S, and set U
Output: An enumeration of all k-length extensions to S using elements in U without repetitions
for each e in U do
Add e to the end of S
Remove e from U /*e is now being used*/
if k == 1 then
Test whether S is a configuration that solves the puzzle
if S solves the puzzle then
return "Solution found: " S
else
PuzzleSolve(k-1,S,U) /*a recursive call*/
Remove e from the end of S
Add e back to U e is now considered as unused
This algorithm enumerates every possible size-k ordered subset of U, and tests each subset for being
a possible solution to our puzzle. For summation puzzles, U = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and each position
in the sequence corresponds to a given letter. For example, the first position could stand for b, the
second for o, the third for y, and so on.